# Permanently allow apps downloaded from "anywhere"

Tags: macos, applications, settings

[image: Screenshot of "Choosing 'Anywhere' makes your Mac less secure." popup]

I want to trust unidentified developers' applications. I've gone to System Preferences > Security & Privacy and tried to enable "Allow apps downloaded from: Anywhere", but OS X claims it will reset my "Anywhere" selection after 30 days of inactivity. Actually, I don't want OS X to make it unusually difficult for me to use my software, ever. Is it possible to make this selection permanent?

Comment: Not on Yosemite but on Mavericks, you can ctrl+click -open on the app to allow download

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It took me some time to figure this out but you can disable it through a global preference using the terminal:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.security GKAutoRearm -bool NO
```

This will disable the auto rearming of the Gatekeeper in OS X. Tested on both Yosemite and Mavericks

Comment: Looking forward to this working in a month; for now I'll take your word for it!

Comment: Does not seem to work on Mojave

Comment: @JacobRaccuia you can try `sudo spctl --master-disable` but I haven’t tested it

Answer (score -2):

Not enough to get the password, you need to change a new one (password) to allow apps downloaded from a particular source can run.

Comment: What do passwords have to do with Gatekeeper here?