# Disable the use of the "com.apple.quarantine" extended attribute on Mojave

Tags: macos, mojave, security, extended-attributes

I recently got Mojave. Could somebody tell me whether it's possible to disable the use of the "com.apple.quarantine" extended attribute, for all apps that I have now or will ever download in the future? Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I understood your question clearly, here is the solution that you can use to disable it completely.

1. Open **Terminal**
2. Type following command

   ```
   sudo defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO
   ```
3. After that, reboot, and you should be set.

**If you want to disable quarantine for files already downloaded**

1. Open **Terminal**.
2. Execute the following command:

   ```
   xattr -l /path/to/application/applicationName.app
   ```
3. You will see output similar to:

   [image]

To remove an extended attribute manually, type the following command in Terminal

```
   xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/application/applicationName.app
```

Comment: @Tetsujin and Udhy - This command looks familiar from the last time I used OS X (El Capitan back in 2016!). Ironically, I've just realised that this isn't the massive issue that it first seemed to be, since I now have all apps that I need installed and not nagging me. But if/when I find the need to install another, I'll let you guys know if it does indeed work. However, Udhy can have the accepted answer rep for now :-) Tetsujin, thanks anyway for trying to help and for being "fastest gun in the west"...perhaps the fastest gun I've ever seen on a SE site!

Comment: Hmm...nope that command doesn't actually seem to have helped - just downloaded a new .pkg installer and still got the dialog, even after right-clicking as suggested by @Tetsujin :-( I guess I can live with the annoyance of the popup dialog now, since I will rarely download/install anything else on this Mac. Just wanted to warn future readers that another solution is necessary.

Comment: Thank you!  `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine MyApp.app` was the only way to allow my application to access its resource files.  Apparently the quarantine flag prevents `chdir` calls, which I use to load resources in the directory adjacent to the app.

Is this why everyone releases Mac software in dmg images, to avoid Apple stupidly tagging everything extracted from zip files?  Such a pain.

Answer (score 6):

First run, instead of double-clicking, right click & select Open.

Done.

Alternatively, disable SIP & you get this option back, in Security & Privacy…

[image]

… though you still get some 'are you sure?' messages, you can just say 'OK'

*After comments:* You may also need to set this in Terminal

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.security GKAutoRearm -bool NO
```

From [Permanently allow apps downloaded from "anywhere"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196729/permanently-allow-apps-downloaded-from-anywhere)

Comment: Dude, I would seriously give you +1000 votes if I could. Will definitely accept this answer as soon as I'm able (in 6 minutes apparently lol). Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually it seems as though disabling SIP on Mojave doesn't actually bring back that "anywhere" option...I've disabled it, restarted and still can't allow from anywhere :-(

Comment: hmmm… maybe I also did this… https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/198123/85275 - adding to answer

Comment: OK will give that a go...thanks again :-)

Comment: Wish you luck - let us know how it goes. The pic, btw, was from my own Mojave Mac, so I've obviously managed to do it at some point… I just don't remember quite *how* ;)

Comment: LOL no worries thanks mate :-) I tried the command and it didn't do anything to that pref pane, but maybe a restart is required...? Will lyk once I get a chance to restart (running a long batch job atm :P)