# How to disable com.apple.quarantine on Catalina

Tags: security, catalina, extended-attributes

I am constantly downloading files from our servers and they get marked with the *com.apple.quarantine* attribute.

How can I forever (and ever, until the universe collapses) prevent the OS from setting this attribute?

- I know why it is there
- I know how to remove it
- There are other answers, that don't work on Catalina, regarding this, like [Disable the use of the "com.apple.quarantine" extended attribute on Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373176/disable-the-use-of-the-com-apple-quarantine-extended-attribute-on-mojave) so it is not a duplicate

It looks like on Catalina the *'defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO'* solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

As a *workaround*, I'd create a **Automator** *Folder Action*, attached to the **Downloads** folder, with a **Run AppleScript** *action*, setting **Shell:** `/bin/bash` and  **Pass input:** `as arguments`, using the *example* `bash` *code* below,  until a more permanent answer comes about.

```
for f in "$@"
do
    [ ! -d "${f}.download" ] || continue
    xattr -d com.apple.quarantine "$f"
done
```

[image]

---

<sub>**Note:** The *example* `bash` *code* contains limited *error handling*. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted.</sub>